# Will functions run twice with asyncio.gather(create_task(task))

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

What will be happened, if I run:

```py
tasks = []
for item in items:
  tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(f(item)))

res = asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

Will functions run twice? After `create_task` and after `gather`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that you must **await** `asyncio.gather()` for them to run at all.

Once that is fixed, the functions will run only once. `create_task()` submits them to the event loop. After that, they will run during the next `await`. `asyncio.gather()` simply ensures that the calling coroutine awaits their completion. For example, this will run them in two portions:

```
tasks = []
for item in items:
  tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(f(item)))

await asyncio.sleep(1)   # here they start running and run for a second
res = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)  # here we wait for them to complete
```

Comment: What will be the difference if I run with `create_task` and without it? Just run `await asyncio.gather(*tasks)`

Comment: @EvgenyShestakov `gather()` runs `create_task()` for you internally, so there should be no difference.